# how to get horizontal and vertical lines on mouse hover?

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent, draw, pixel

NET programming.I have a image of a map with latitudes and longitudes on its borders .now when i drag the mouse on the map i should get a rectangle with one vertex at the mouse point and opposite one  at the top left corner of map ,so that i can exactly pin pointedly locate the pixel with latitude and longitude.to be clear it should appear as a rectangle when we drag mouse on the screen.I have a code which is partially working

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // "e.X" and "e.Y" are used to get MousePositionX and MousePositionY
        rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // This makes sure that the left mouse button is pressed.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves
            rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
```

I don't know where the problem exactly is but could draw a rectangle at run time.any one please help me with changes in the code.

Comment: You say your code is partially working -- what isn't working about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tafa's Answer works.

I only got two additions:

1. In the MouseDown Method you should
   also use the following code.   So
   once you click somewhere in the map
   you get a rectangle even when not
   moving the mouse.

   ```
   rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.X, e.Y);
   ```
2. In the MouseMove method I would use the following code, to not create new Rectangles whenever you move the mouse:

   ```
   rect.Width = e.X;  
   rect.Height = e.Y;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Two simple changes required;

Instead of `this.Invalidate()` call `pictureBox1.Invalidate()`.

In the mouseMove method generate rectangle as;

```
rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.X, e.Y);
```

Since you want the top left corner (0,0) be the other corner of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating your own canvas control (**[Edit: which inherits from PictureBox]**), with double buffering enabled. This will reduce flicker while drawing.

```
public partial class DrawingCanvas : PictureBox
{
    public DrawingCanvas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(
              ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
              ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
              ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    private Point start = new Point(0, 0);
    private Point end = new Point(0, 0);

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        start = e.Location;
        end = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // This makes sure that the left mouse button is pressed.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            end = e.Location;

        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int top = start.Y < end.Y ? start.Y : end.Y;
        int left = start.X < end.X ? start.X : end.X;
        int width = end.X - start.X; if (width < 0) width = -width;
        int height = end.Y - start.Y; if (height < 0) height = -height;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `DrawRectangle` doesn't accept negative width or height, so you must take care of this in the `OnPaint` method.

Once you've added this control to your project, compile the project. Your custom control should be available on top of the Toolbox window in Visual Studio. If it isn't, you can either right click the Toolbox and select `Choose Items...` to add your canvas to the toolbox, or simply add a `Panel` control to your `Form`, open the `Form.Designer.cs` file, and replace all `Panel` references with your  `DrawingCanvas` (or whatever name you choose).

When setting the background image, use the `BackgroundImage` property.